# how to pass a Socket EndPoint to WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, file-transfer, endpoint

Im using WCF to transfer Files

in the client side [WINFORM]

```
private void Send(TransferEntry Entry, int bufferSize)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Entry.SrcPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            long sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            using (Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                listener.Bind(endpoint);
                listener.Listen(1);
                client.Receive(listener.LocalEndPoint, Entry.DestPath, Entry.Size, bufferSize);
                //i get an exception here.
                using (Socket socket = listener.Accept())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        socket.Send(buffer, 0, count, SocketFlags.None);
                        sum += count;
                        worker.ReportProgress((int)((sum * 100) / Entry.Size));
                    } while (sum < Entry.Size);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

at WCF [service]:
on IFileManager.cs:

```
[OperationContract]
    void Receive(System.Net.EndPoint endpoint, string destPath, long size, int bufferSize);
```

on FileManagerService.cs:

```
public void Receive(EndPoint endpoint, string destPath, long size, int bufferSize)
    {
        using (Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            client.Connect(endpoint);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                long sum = 0;
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = client.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                } while (sum < size);
                fs.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

**then i got this exception on the Client side [Winform]**:

`System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:endpoint. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.Net.IPEndPoint' with data contract name 'IPEndPoint:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.`

Why does this happens only when i pass `EndPoint` parameter! and how can i make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is expecting an `EndPoint`, but you are sending an `IPEndPoint.`

You can fix this by telling the service to expect an `IPEndPoint` using a [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx).